# mysql if column contain

Tags: php, mysql

i have a table with data like this (table A)

```
id | key  | status
-----------------
1  | dg12 | done
2  | dg12 |
```

and like this (table B)

```
id   | Name  | status
------------------
dg12 | Dummy |
```

i want to update table B status with this condition

if table A status in row 1 and 2 (i means not containing " " value) is done then dg12 status in table B is done...

how can i do that?? using php+mysql, anyone can help please??
thanks before

Comment: if the relation status in tableA key="dg12" and status="done" -> remove row in tableB where id="dg12" ?

Comment: So the constraint is that table A has to have two records with 'status' != null before table B gets updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE 
    tableB AS b
SET 
    b.status = 'done'
WHERE 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableA AS a WHERE a.key = b.id) 
    = 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableA AS a WHERE a.key = b.id AND a.status = 'done')
```

**OR**

```
UPDATE 
    tableB AS b
SET 
    b.status = 'done'
WHERE 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableA AS a WHERE a.key = b.id AND a.status != 'done') = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Update tableA a,tableb b
SET b.status=CASE WHEN (select count(*) from tableB where id=a.key group by key,status) > 0 then 'Done' else b.status end
where a.key=b.id
```

Comment: Wrong! "So the constraint is that table A has to have two records with 'status' != null before table B gets updated?...Yes..."

Answer (score 1):

It can be even shorter:

```
UPDATE tableB b
SET b.`status` = 'done'
WHERE 'done' = ALL(SELECT `status` FROM tableA a WHERE a.key = b.id)
```

Test data here:

```
drop table if exists tableA;
create table tableA(id int, `key` varchar(10), status varchar(10));
insert into tableA values (1, 'dg12', 'done'), (2,'dg12', '');
drop table if exists tableB;
create table tableB(id varchar(10), name varchar(10), status varchar(10));
insert into tableB values ('dg12','Dummy', '');
```

Query from above executed:

`0 rows affected`

```
update tableA set status='done' where id = 2;
```

Query from above executed:

`1 row affected`

Read more about subqueries with `ALL` [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/all-subqueries.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
   TRUE
FROM
   tableA
WHERE
   key = ?
   AND status <> 'done'
LIMIT 1
...
// all tableA for key="dg12" are "done"
if (!$query->execute("dg12")->num_rows()) {
   UPDATE tableB SET status = "done" WHERE id = ?
   ...
   $query->execute("dg12");
}
```

Let me know if you don't understand as this is largely pseudo-php.

This also does not account for the possibility of tableA containing *no* rows on that key.  Not sure that can happen.